# After using the image_picker package to select a picture in Flutter web, a "Select File" button appears in the upper left corner of the browser

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use flutter to make a website, but when I use image_picker to select a picture, a "select file" button and file name appear in the upper left corner of the browser, which cannot be clicked or eliminated. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

code:

```
static Future<XFile?> pickSingleImage() async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

    final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    return image;
  }
```

I have tried using native method and other package to solve this problem,but not doing well.I'm wondering if I can keep using this package and solve the problem at the same time.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the button?

Comment: @Tayan I don't have that button in my code.That's why I'm confusing about the appear of the button